# LeftScroll when times up

Tags: jquery, animation

can't really get around this problem.
I am making a quiz, and I use a scrollLeft-jQuery-function to get to the next question.
So I have a timer, and when that ends I wish the scrollLeft function to be called.
This works with the first question, however, not the next. I get that it is because it just targets the first href="#" of the `.aAnswers li a`.
How do I get so it targets the right?

HTML: http://www.carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/

JS:

```
function timesUp(){
            $('#timerBar').animate({'width':'0px'}, 1800, function(){
                nextQuestion(function(){
                    resetTimer();
                }); 
            });                 
}

function nextQuestion(event){
    var $anchor = $('.qAnswers a');
     $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
        }, 2000, function(){
            resetTimer();
        });

     event.preventDefault();
}

function resetTimer(){
    $('#timerBar').css('width', '100%');
    timesUp();
}

function stopTimer(){
    $('#timerBar').stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you have an error: "TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function".  It may be preventing the flow you are expecting.

Comment: Well I edit it out, didn't do much of a change. Thanks for pointing out though.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting always the same link without updating it, try this

```
// >> define here
var $anchors = $('.qContainer');
var i = 0;
function nextQuestion(event){
     $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: $anchors.get(i).position().left
        }, 2000, function(){
            resetTimer();
        });
     event.preventDefault();
     // >> update here
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Your code is quite confusing (ie: lots of ids and classes etc), you should try to use the minimum amount of id as possible to avoi confusion. BTW look my edited answer, should point you in the right direction. Again the task is very simple, the code is confusing, the exact opposite of what coding should be ;)

Comment: Ok, good tip for future. Still no luck with the jQuery though... hmm